# Shortcode button not launching modal

Tags: wordpress

We are on Wordpress 4.5 with CiviCRM 4.7.6 but this error also occurred on 4.4 with 4.7.2.  When clicking the CiviCRM shortcode button for a Post or Page, the user is redirected to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fshortcode&reset=1 rather than being presented a modal window that allows the user what type of shortcode to put into the page or post.  Has anyone else run into this?